# UFW blocks SSL connections Varnish/Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, varnish, ubuntu-12.04, ufw

I have installed Virtualmin on a Ubuntu 12.04 server and I'm using LAMP stack with Varnish (:80) in front of Apache (:8000). However, I cannot access https when UFW is enabled. When I disable UFW, all works fine.

Here is what UFW logging shows when I attempt to access a website via https:

```
Dec 14 05:42:29 localhost kernel: [64491.327263] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=e4:11:5b:e5:ef:8c:00:d0:02:8f:f0:00:08:00 SRC=MY_IP_ADDRESS DST=SERVER_IP_ADDRESS LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=115 ID=2524 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56430 DPT=20000 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Here is my UFW ruleset:

```
$ ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2221                       ALLOW       Anywhere
10000                      ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
21                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Secure              ALLOW       Anywhere
2221                       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
10000                      ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Secure (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Does anyone have any pointers how to fix this problem?

Thank you for your time.